# provisioning profile shows wrong application name when publishing to AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, provisioning-profile

It seems like I've been bitten by the provisioning profile bug.  I followed a few guidelines on how to fix my situation and I refreshed profiles and project settings multiple times but I still get stuck when submitting to the iOS App Store.

Here are a few basics.  First of all on the Apple Developer Portal I have got the distribution profile for my new app (my old app which I experimented with years ago doesn't even have a profile)
[image]

Second thing I have verified is that my application is actually using the profile when code signing. I have refreshed the profiles using the preferences dialogs and in the project settings I have explicitly set this up:
[image]

When I go through the wizard to publish the app to the app store it looks like when I am asked to choose the profile to sign with the Application seems to be the wrong application!

[image]

Any thoughts on what else I can be doing wrong?  Any other places to check?

Comment: On iTunes Connect have you clicked submit new version for your app.

Comment: ^^ This, and have you tried producing an archive and signing it that way instead of going through the publishing process?

Comment: I have not.  This is actually a brand new app, not a version of an old app.  Why is my old app showing up?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  The problem was that I didn't have a corresponding application set up a new application.  It's not enough to just set it up in the developer center.  Wyatt Mufson - your hint led me down the right path!

When you add the second app the last screen start having a drop down for the application and then you can select the right app that matches the provisioning profile